# Adding event trigger to dynamically created element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add an event trigger to element with class `.youtube_add_to_playlist`. This element is added dynamically.

**What I've tried so far**

1. I wrapped the whole code into `$(document).ready(function() { });`
2. I replaced:

```js
jQuery('.youtube_add_to_playlist').click(function(e)
```

with

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.youtube_add_to_playlist', function(e)
```

The event trigger is still not added to the element. Clearly, I am missing something. Likely how I am using `.on()` inside a function...?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '';
  var OAUTH2_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'];
  var init = false;
  var youtube_button = null;

  googleApiClientReady = function() {
    gapi.auth.init(function() {
      window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    });
  }

  function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
      client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
      immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
  }

  // Handle the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
  function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    jQuery('.youtube_add_to_playlist').off('click');
    ///jQuery('.youtube_add_to_playlist').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(document).on('click', '.youtube_add_to_playlist', function(e) {
      youtube_button = this;

      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        addToPlaylist(jQuery(this).attr("data-youtube-video-id"), jQuery(this).attr("data-type"));
      } else {
        init = true;
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
          immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
      }
      return false;
    });

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
      // Authorization was successful. Hide authorization prompts and show
      // content that should be visible after authorization succeeds.
      jQuery('.pre-auth').hide();
      jQuery('.post-auth').show();
      loadAPIClientInterfaces();

      jQuery('#add_to_wl').click(function(e) {
        youtube_button = this;
        addToPlaylist(jQuery(this).attr("data-youtube-video-id"), jQuery(this).attr("data-type"));
      });
    }
  }

  function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
      if (init) {
        init = false;
        addToPlaylist(jQuery(youtube_button).attr("data-youtube-video-id"), jQuery(youtube_button).attr("data-type"));
      }
    });
  }

  function addToPlaylist(videoId, playlistType) {
    console.log("add to playlist type : " + playlistType);
    if (playlistType != "WL" && playlistType != "HL") {
      var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
        mine: true,
        part: 'contentDetails'
      });

      request.execute(function(response) {
        var playlistId = response.result.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists[playlistType];

        if (typeof playlistId != 'undefined') {
          console.log("found playlist id : " + playlistId);
          insertToPlaylist(videoId, playlistId);
        } else {
          console.log("playlist not found");
        }
      });
    } else {
      insertToPlaylist(videoId, playlistType);
    }
  }

  function insertToPlaylist(videoId, playlistId) {
    var details = {
      videoId: videoId,
      kind: 'youtube#video'
    };
    var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
      part: 'snippet',
      resource: {
        snippet: {
          playlistId: playlistId,
          resourceId: details
        }
      }
    });

    request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log(response);

      if (!response.code) {
        // do stuff
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The **What I've tried so far** part is very nice. Should be required for all questions. +1

Comment: Who adds this element, when and where?

Comment: The delegated event handler should work fine. It would help to see an MCVE where you append the HTML too. Also check there's no calls which `return false` or `stopPropagation` of the click event up to the document. Also note that your `off()` call is redundant as the `.youtube_add_to_playlist` never has an event handler attached to it

Comment: @CBroe The element is added by a different function that outputs HTML. It is added dynamically when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Do a `console.log` inside the `jQuery(document).on('click', ...` function, and check if it logs anything. If it does, there is something else wrong in your code.

Comment: As @Rory said, you are not removing any event handler with `jQuery('.youtube_add_to_playlist').off('click')`, so that also means that with `jQuery(document).on('click', '.youtube_add_to_playlist', ...)` you add a new one, every time `handleAuthResult` is called (and that might even call itself recursively) ... does not explain why you would not see it firing at all, but is likely not what you really want here either.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think as well the problem is within the functions. I tested this code by adding a div element dynamically with class `youtube_add_to_playlist` and the event was not attached.

Comment: Chances are pretty good that the HTML loaded on the page before you try to attach your events. I'd wrap the whole thing in a `setTimeout` set to like 5 or 10 seconds so you can be sure that's is/isn't the problem. If it is, then we can work from there, otherwise well, you've ruled one thing out.

Comment: **Update:** The problem was that I forgot to load the `googleApiClientReady` JS file. It's one of those days.